# $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P (A' \cap B')$

Tags: probability

$P(A \cup B) = 1 - P (A' \cap B')$

Conceptually I'm fine. I drew a Venn Diagram and I understand the problem. I think I turned the right side into the left side correctly, but if someone could verify I'd appreciate it. I expanded $P (A' \cap B')$ into $P(A')*P(B')$.

$P(A')= 1-P(A)$. Then, use the same logic for $P(B')$.
Then,
$$1 - P (A' \cap B')$$
$$=1-[(1-P(A))*(1-P(B))]$$
$$=1-[1-P(B)-P(A)+P(A)P(B)]$$
$$=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$$
$$=P(A \cup B)$$

How do we feel about this?

Comment: What does $A'$ mean? How does it relate to $A$?

Comment: $A'$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: It's incorrect because you cannot assume $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. That would be true only for independent events $A$ and $B$, not in general.

Comment: Hint: Use de Morgan's law in set theory.

Comment: Yes: Note that that independence assumption got used twice, so the error "canceled out." Your Venn diagram is what M. Vinay is calling deMorgan's laws. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**
$$
P(A \cap B) \color{red}{\neq} P(A) \cdot P(B) 
$$
for example take the uniform density on $[0,1]$ and $A = [0,2/3], B = [0,1/3]$. We have
$$
P(A \cap B) = P([0,1/3]) = 1 / 3, P(A) \cdot P(B) = (2 / 3) \cdot (1 / 3) = 2 / 9
$$
so your proof unfortunately is not valid.

**Hint:**
$$
P(C) = 1 - P(C') \text{ and by De Morgan's laws } (A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'
$$

Comment: After I apply De Morgan's Law: $P(A\cup B)=1-P(A\cup B)'$, does the conclusion simply follow? Or, is there a step in between applying it and showing $P(A\cup B)=P(A\cup B)$?

Comment: @VincentValentine I don't believe there's an extra step in there. Since $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$ we have $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P((A \cup B)') = 1 - P(A' \cap B')$

Comment: @VincentValentine no problem, glad to help! Probability is quite a fun subject (IMO), so enjoy!